# Libav: unable to read frames with mp4 files from d.tube

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, libav

I am trying to read frames with mp4 files from [d.tube](http://d.tube). There is a problem specifically with videos from this website whether from stream or file. When I am trying to use `avformat_find_stream_info()`, I got the following message:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1226040] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1226040] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 854x480, 287 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1226040] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, 128 kb/s): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
```

I tried comparing with mp4 files from Youtube, but there is no problem at all. After I couldn't find the solution, I skipped this message and continued, but there is `Invalid data found when processing input`
 error from `av_read_frame()`. Probably, it is from the same cause.

In contrast, there is no problem using ffmpeg commands to get video information and extract frames. I also tried with different version of ffmpeg, but the same result. The example code I am trying to modify can be found on [Youtube-test](https://github.com/sabyahsan/Youtube-test/blob/master/src/mm_parser.c). In addition, I already added the config of ffmpeg with`--enable-decoder=h264 --enable-demuxer=h264 --enable-demuxer=mp4 --enable-demuxer=h264 --enable-parser=h264 --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264`.

Comment: You say _"In contrast, there is no problem using ffmpeg commands"_ does this mean FFmpeg on command line accepts DTube files okay but `libAV` will not work? Anyways I checked D.Tube video bytes and they're fine so I'm not sure what you can do. They're same format as Youtube (even same "produced by Google" copyright in `soun` atom for both file headers).

Comment: @VC.One Yes, it works on ffmpeg command line, but not libAV(tested with an [example](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2avio_reading_8c-example.html)). When I tried with `av_dump_format()` to see file info, I couldn't see "produced by Google". Is it normal? The files I downloaded from DTube are from both curl and browser's download.

I just found that `MP4Box -hint` solves this problem if I process a file with that command. I think something similar like `qt-faststart` will also fix this. As I googled it, it's to rearrange and move atom to the front.